# In Magento with base currency India not able to make payment using Paypal but with any other currency its going fine why?

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am trying to make payment by using Indian currency but its showing the message

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

**but its working properly for all other currency.**

Answer (score 3):

Indian currency is not supported by PayPal products.
PayPal Payments Pro and Payflow Pro with PayPal as the Processor (US)
AUD – Australian Dollar
CAD – Canadian Dollar
EUR – Euro
GBP – Pounds Sterling
JPY – Japanese Yen
USD – U.S. Dollar

You can use PayU Payment Gateway for india. 
Refer this link: https://www.payubiz.in/

Check these recommended Magento extensions for unsupported currencies in Paypal :
(Free) https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento
(Paid) http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-multi-currency.html
(Paid) https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-all-currencies.html

However, if you’re uncomfortable with using either of the two, 
another option that you may consider is to convert the base currency (which is INR in your case) to a supported currency (say USD).